# Creating JSON String from Two Columns in PySpark GroupBy

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a data frame that looks like so:

```py
>>> l = [('a', 'foo', 1), ('b', 'bar', 1), ('a', 'biz', 6), ('c', 'bar', 3), ('c', 'biz', 2)]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ('uid', 'code', 'level')) 
>>> df.show()
+---+----+-----+
|uid|code|level|
+---+----+-----+
|  a| foo|    1|
|  b| bar|    1|
|  a| biz|    6|
|  c| bar|    3|
|  c| biz|    2|
+---+----+-----+
```

What I'm trying to do is group the `code` and `level` values into a `list` of `dict` and dump that list as a JSON string so that I can save the data frame to disk. The result would look like:

```py
>>> df.show()
+---+--------------------------+
|uid|           json           |
+---+--------------------------+
|  a| '[{"foo":1}, {"biz":6}]' |
|  b| '[{"bar":1}]'            |
|  c| '[{"bar":3}, {"biz":2}]' |
+---+--------------------------+
```

I'm still pretty new to use PySpark and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to get this result. I almost surely need a `groupBy` and I've tried implementing this by creating a new `StringType` column called "json" and then using the `pandas_udf` decorator but I'm getting errors about unhasable types, because, as I've found out, the way I'm accessing the data is accessing the whole column, not just the row.

```
>>> df = df.withColumn('json', F.list(''))
>>> schema = df.schema
>>> @pandas_udf(schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
..: def to_json(pdf):
..:     return pdf.assign(serial=json.dumps({pdf.code:pdf.level}))
```

I've considered using string concatenation between the two columns and using `collect_set` but that feels wrong as well since it has the potential to write to disk that which can't be JSON loaded just because it has a string representation. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for a `pandas_udf` in this case. `to_json`, `collect_list` and `create_map` should be all you need:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.groupby('uid').agg(
  f.to_json(
    f.collect_list(
      f.create_map('code', 'level')
    )
  ).alias('json')
).show(3, False)
+---+---------------------+
|uid|json                 |
+---+---------------------+
|c  |[{"bar":3},{"biz":2}]|
|b  |[{"bar":1}]          |
|a  |[{"foo":1},{"biz":6}]|
+---+---------------------+
```

Comment: what if using only one column here i.e. level , i want to give me own structure to json ? For example ,   `[ {first : 3, status : null} , {second : 2, status : "pending"} ]` and keep uid column as it is.