# pyspark convert json and group by

Tags: pyspark

I have this dataframe in pyspark.

```
+----------------------+------------------+------------+------------+
|      transaction_date|                id|latest_quote|policy_price|
+----------------------+------------------+------------+------------+
|            16/12/2022|0063t000013qmPFAAY|2022-11-25  |      899.18|
|            16/12/2022|0063t000013qQNTAA2|2022-11-30  |     3147.78|
+----------------------+------------------+------------+------------+
```

and i need this.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|unique_column                                                                         
|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"transaction_date":"16/12/2022", "trans_opp":[                                       
|
| {"id":"0063t000013qmPFAAY", "latest_quote":"2022-11-25", "policy_price":"899.18"},   
|
| {"id":"0063t000013qQNTAA2", "latest_quote":"2022-11-30", "policy_price":" 3147.78"}]}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The idea is all rows stay in one column call unique_column and one row,

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738953/creating-json-string-from-two-columns-in-pyspark-groupby

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use exactly the same dataframe you used to ask the question, but I the column names are the in my solution:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 2, 3, 4),
    (1, 6, 7, 8)
], ['transaction_date', 'id', 'latest_quote', 'policy_price'])

df = (
    df
    .groupBy('transaction_date')
    .agg(f.collect_list(f.struct(f.col('id'), f.col('latest_quote'), f.col('policy_price'))).alias('trans_opp'))
    .withColumn('unique_column', f.struct(f.col('transaction_date'), f.col('trans_opp')))
    .withColumn('unique_column', f.to_json(f.col('unique_column')))
    .select('unique_column')
)

df.show(truncate= False)
```

output:

```
+---------------+
|unique_column  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"transaction_date":1,"trans_opp":[{"id":2,"latest_quote":3,"policy_price":4},{"id":6,"latest_quote":7,"policy_price":8}]}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```